# How to configure external USB touchpad for a laptop

Tags: ubuntu, x11, mouse, touchpad

I have a laptop that, obviously, comes with a touchpad and a keyboard. However, I have an USB keyboard with integrated touchpad that better suits my needs. I use Ubuntu 13.10 and I cannot find how to configure the external touchpad sensitivity, or any other options.

The default touchpad settings tool from Ubuntu works fine, but it only changes the settings for the laptop's default touchpad. I also tried `gpointing-device-settings`, no luck.

Google's search results only mention touchpads from laptops, nothing about a second touchpad input device... How would I achieve this?

Here is the output of `xinput`: http://pastebin.ca/2643065

Comment: Take a look at the output from `xinput` for starters.

Comment: Also check out these Q&As: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=xinput+touchpad

Comment: @slm: thank you. `xinput` shows the usb keyboard as a slave pointer and as slave keyboard, which seems correct. I did check details for both the internal touchpad and for the usb-attached touchpad. It seems synaptics is used for the internal touchpad, and evdev for the external touchpad.

see the output here: https://pastebin.ca/2643065